# NHibernate: help translating an hql query to use criteria api instead

Tags: nhibernate, hql, criteria-api

I have the following hql query which I'd like to switch over to the criteria API

```
select a.Id as Id, a.Name as Name, a.ActiveStatus as ActiveStatus, 
dbo.GetActivityStartDate(a.Id) as StartDate, 
dbo.GetActivityEndDate(a.Id) as EndDate, 
coalesce(ac.Id,0) As CategoryId, 
coalesce(ac.Name,'') As CategoryName 
from Activity as a 
left outer join a.Category as ac
```

Obviously the initial properties on the select line are trivial (Projections.Property); my question is..how do I map the remaining 4 properties?

I have a custom dialect that registers `dbo.GetActivityStartDate` and `dbo.GetActivityEndDate` as standard SQL functions - so that much is already taken care of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So...it turned out that I needed to register the "ISNULL" function with my custom dialect; once I did that, it was a simple matter of using the Projections.SqlFunction to extract the data in the format I required.